# Get html from Razor template (for sending e-mail body) in ASP Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I need to convert the Razer template to html conversion in ASP.Net Core.

[image]

[image]

```
// TODO: Get html

string body = GetCompiledHtmlStringFromRazor
    ("~/Views/EmailTemplates/PasswordResetEmailTemplate.cshtml", viewModel);
```

Any source code for making this process simple.. ?

Answer (score 0):

For .Net use **RazorEngine**

https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine

Use .NetCore use **RazorEngine.NetCore**

https://github.com/fouadmess/RazorEngine

[image]